# Split string up to nth occurrence of separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a string -

`"one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight"`.

Now I want to split this string with ':' but till first 3 occurence of ':'.

Expected output -

`['one','two','three','four:five:six:seven:eight']`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) takes a `maxsplit` parameter other than the separator, which does exactly that:

```
s.split(':',3)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four:five:six:seven:eight']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split for all then construct the shape of your list as you desire.

```py
str_list = "one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight"
my_list = str_list.split(":")

print([my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2], ":".join(my_list[3:])])
```

The output will be:

```py
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four:five:six:seven:eight']
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you want to use the regex package: re

```
import re
re.split(':', "one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight", maxsplit=3)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four:five:six:seven:eight']
```

And if you want to compile the reg-expression

```
import re
re_colon = re.compile(':')
re_colon("one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight", maxsplit=3)
# ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four:five:six:seven:eight']
```

Answer (score 0):

The split function in python can take 2 arguments i.e 
First argument is the character by using which you have to split the string.
The second argument is the max_split, an integer for the maximum no. of splits.

```
given_string = "one:two:three:four:five:six:seven:eight"

print(given_string.split(':',3))
```